# Moving WorkSheets from one Workbook to another and updating formula (links)

Tags: reference, move, formula, worksheet, excel

I've solved this, tweaked the code a bit and now it works fine. I won't attempt to post the new code, as every time I try I end up with bits of code above and below the code block.

---

We are experiencing major problems with shared workbooks, so as a quick fix I've written some code to move a number of worksheets out of the shared workbook to individual workbooks, which each user can open exclusively.

When I move them (as described above) it removes the worksheet from the main workbook, creates a new workbook with the one (same) worksheet AND updates all formula (links become external to new workbook).

When I try to move them back, it 'copies' the worksheet back into the main workbook, but leaves the worksheet in the individual workbook, AND does NOT update the formula (in fact it appears to break them, lots of #REF after the process).

What I'd like it to do is remove the worksheet from the individual workbook, moving it back to the main workbook and update the links.

Here's my code:

```
Public Sub ResourceMerge()

'-- Rich Head, 5/12/2012
'-- Merges the separated resource worksheets into the main workbook (sledge hammer to fix
'-- shared workbooks issue) which has arisen since XP rollout

    'Handle errors
    On Error GoTo Err

    'Variables
    Dim wbResourceNames(1 To 20), cv, myName As String, _
        ws As Worksheet, _
        wb, targetwb As Workbook, _
        x, i As Integer

    'Before any changes made, backup the master workbook
    myName = ActiveWorkbook.Name                                        'Get current workbook name
    myName = Mid(myName, 1, Len(myName) - 4)                            'Remove the .xls"
    myName = myName & "_backup2_" & Format(Date, "d mmm yyyy") & ".xls" 'Add "_backup current date.xls"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs myName                                    'Save a copy with the new name
    Set targetwb = Application.ActiveWorkbook                           'Store the main workbook

    'Make the people control panel sheet active and select cell B8 (row above first name)
    Set ws = Sheets("People Control Panel")
    ws.Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("B8").Activate

    'Loop down through the names (ignoring any Spare) to get all the resource names
    x = 0
    Do Until x = 20                                         'Assumes maximum 20 resources
        x = x + 1
        Debug.Print x
        ActiveCell.Offset(Rowoffset:=1).Activate            'Move down one cell
        If Left(ActiveCell.Value, 5) = "Spare" Then         'Ignore 'spare' rows
            GoTo Loopy
        End If
        wbResourceNames(x) = ActiveCell.Value               'Get the resource name
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wbResourceNames(x))         'Open the individual resource worksheet
        'Move sheet back into main workbook
        wb.Sheets(1).Move _
        after:=targetwb.Sheets(targetwb.Sheets("OFF SHORE"))
        wb.Close                                            'Close new workbook
Loopy:
    Loop                                                    'Do next resource

'    ActiveWorkbook.Save                                     'Save the reduced master

GoTo Endy                                                   'All done

Err:
    If Err = 9 Then                                         'Incorrect worksheet name?
        MsgBox "The VBA code has trapped an error ('subscript out of range'), this is likely to be " & _
            "because a resource name from the 'People Control Panel' (a hidden worksheet) does not " & _
            "match the name of the worksheet; please delete this spreadsheet and any individual " & _
            "spreadsheets created and start again (change the name of the backup sheet created - by " & _
            "removing the '_backup2 and date' from the filename, correct the worksheet name error, save " & _
            "the workbook and run the macro again)."
        GoTo Endy
    End If
    MsgBox "Oops... VBA code error, number: " & Err & ", with a description of: " & Error(Err)
Endy:
End Sub
```

Comment: Edited to mark as solved

Comment: Your solution would help me a lot. Could you post it as an answer to your own question, in true SO style?